# Having wordpress page accesss issue under sub-directory

Tags: pages, content, troubleshooting

I have hosted website at sub-directory but pages content is not showing and only header and footer display at pages. My index file have this code for pages display. It was working fine at root directory under localhost. The site_url and home_url under wp_options have been set with sub-directory path.

```
<?php if (have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php //post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="post-header">
                    <div class="date"><?php //the_time( 'M j y' ); ?></div>
                    <h2><a href="<?php //the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="author"><?php //the_author(); ?></div>
                </div><!--.post-header-->
                <div class="entry clear">
                    <?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php //woocommerce_content(); ?>                   
                    <?php //wp_link_pages(); ?>
                </div><!--. entry-->

            </div><!-- .post-->
        <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>

        <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif;
```